# Slow SmoothKernelDistribution of WeightedData

Tags: performance-tuning, distributions

Consider some data in the form

```
data = {{x,y,weight(x,y)},...};
```

I make

```
wd = WeightedData[data[[All,{1,2}]],data[[All,3]]];
```

I would like to obtain a smooth PDF for wd.

For this, I tried to use SmoothKernelDistribution:

```
skd=SmoothKernelDistribution[wd, "LeastSquaresCrossValidation", {"Bounded", {{0, Pi}, {0.14, 
   60}}, "Gaussian"}, MaxMixtureKernels -> All, InterpolationPoints \
-> 1000];
```

where the bounds correspond to the true bounds of my data. However, something is wrong, and it stucks. Could you please tell me what may be a reason? And is it possible to generate the PDF in an alternative way?

P.S. data has length ~500k.

Comment: Does changing "LeastSquaresCrossValidation" to Automatic result in a valid response?

Comment: We need a representative sample of the data, preferably a sample that also exhibits whatever problem you are experiencing. Also, while you refer to generating a `PDF` you did not include the code that you used to do this.